# vb.net RDLC report doesn't show report when button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report-viewer2010

In my Vb.net application I use rdlc report and ReportViewer. But it only loads report in the page_load event.
Here is my code

```
Private Sub report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.displayTableAdapter.Fill(Me.aludbDataSet.display)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

When I change it to Button_click event, it doesn't load the report. Code is here

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.displayTableAdapter.Fill(Me.aludbDataSet.display)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

I don't know why this happened. Because both are same code, only the way is different. Now, I want to load the report when the button is clicked. How to do that? Anyone help please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try adding the "Handles" code

> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
>   System.EventArgs) **Handles Button1.Click**

Comment: I didn't understand about it. How it solve my problem? can you explain please

Comment: as I've written, you need the **Handles** keyword at the end of the mothod to handle the click event on that button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yes, @user2021114 you definitely miss the `Handles Button1.Click`